# Not reading partition

Tags: 14.04, mount

I just installed Ubuntu 14.02, I have a 1 TB HDD, the one partition was used for windows the other for personal files. I formatted the windows partition and did a fresh Ubuntu install, but I cannot access my other partition at all. what can I do?

It gives me this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/warp/Grim: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/warp/Grim"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Comment: It looks like you left it hibernated, or resized it so it needs chkdks. Both fixes to NTFS really require Windows. You can force mount read only and backup data and then delete it and recreate as ext4. Better to only have NTFS if dual booting with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a certain solution, but it may help you narrow it down and possibly fix it. If you have a USB thumbdrive, pull "Multisystem" off the Software Center. It allows you to install live (and persistent) Linux OSs to the stick you can boot up with (you just need the .ISO images to feed it. Other Operating Systems too).

Then, just tell your system to boot from USB. Typically re-booting and hitting either F2 or F11 while the first flash-screen appears will drop you into BIOS, and you can put USB temporarily at the top of the boot device list.

This accomplishes two things... Multiboot comes with its own GRUB (and GRUB tools). It can give you a totally independent assessment of your partitions. Then when you boot up into a distro, you'll have a clean OS to compare to working OS.

Sorry I can't be more help, but that's how I figured out I had a corrupted GRUB2. I then just re-ran GRUB from the USB key and that fixed it.

When you're done, go back to BIOS and re-set your primary boot device. Leaving USB or CD ROM at top leaves you vulnerable (but you already know that : ) Hope that helps. I'm far from a linux guru; but it did it for me. First thing I do on any stick is install Puppy Linux using Multiboot. Just for hell or high water...